# Quarkus: Dev Services Fixed Port does not work for me

Tags: quarkus, testcontainers

I'm using:

- Windows 10
- Docker for Windows
- Quarkus 3.0.0.Beta

I want to start quarkus dev services with a mariadb and a **fixed port** in quarkus 3.0.0.Beta. I'm using following configuration in my `application.properties`:

```
quarkus.datasource.devservices.enabled=true
quarkus.datasource.devservices.image=mariadb
quarkus.datasource.devservices.port=3456

quarkus.datasource.url=${QUARKUS_DATASOURCE_URL}
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=mariadb
quarkus.datasource.username=root
quarkus.datasource.password=
```

I have the following dependencies in my gradle build:

```
org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:3.1.2
io.quarkus:quarkus-jdbc-mariadb:3.0.0.Beta1
io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-bom:3.0.0.Beta1
```

The container starts up when I start quarkus dev but then crashes after a while, without the quarkus app finished starting with following error:

```
2023-03-28 19:31:36,244 INFO  [doc.io/.6]] (build-49) Waiting for database connection to become available at jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3456/quarkus using query 'SELECT 1'
2023-03-28 19:33:36,352 ERROR [doc.io/.6]] (build-49) Could not start container: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Container is removed
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.tryStart(GenericContainer.java:496)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.lambda$doStart$0(GenericContainer.java:344)
    at org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.retryUntilSuccess(Unreliables.java:81)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:334)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:322)
    at io.quarkus.devservices.mariadb.deployment.MariaDBDevServicesProcessor$1.startDatabase(MariaDBDevServicesProcessor.java:67)
    at io.quarkus.datasource.deployment.devservices.DevServicesDatasourceProcessor.startDevDb(DevServicesDatasourceProcessor.java:284)
    at io.quarkus.datasource.deployment.devservices.DevServicesDatasourceProcessor.launchDatabases(DevServicesDatasourceProcessor.java:136)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:909)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:282)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1538)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)

2023-03-28 19:33:36,357 ERROR [doc.io/.6]] (build-49) There are no stdout/stderr logs available for the failed container
```

When I start the container manually again in docker, it starts correct and listens correctly on port 3456 and I can connect to it.

Comment: Testcontainers log some information at debug level and something helpful might be missing here. Could you try enabling the debug logging globally just to see if testcontainers log anything?

Comment: i tried to enable the debug logging, in quarkus, but it was producing a very huge log. in which i could not find an error only very much debug information.

Comment: i saw that the mariadb container did not start / instantly just stops, and i took a look at the docker container logs for this unstarted container:

...
2023-03-29 16:13:18+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating database quarkus
2023-03-29 16:13:18+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating user root
2023-03-29 16:13:18+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Giving user root access to schema quarkus
2023-03-29 16:13:18+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Securing system users (equivalent to running mysql_secure_installation)
ERROR 1396 (HY000) at line 21: Operation CREATE USER failed for 'root'@'%'

Comment: Are you sure this config is supposed to work: `quarkus.datasource.username=root`
?

Did you try with another username?

Answer (score 0):

when i upgraded to Quarkus 3.8.2 this problem has not occured again, so i think it has been solved by the quarkus team.